# No Symbols Loaded for Windows.Devices.Radios.dll when trying to swich on Wi-Fi or Bluetooth

Tags: c#, wpf, bluetooth, wifi

I am trying to switch on Bluetooth and Wi-Fi adapter from my C# WPF app
Here's my code:

```
    private async Task<bool> SwitchOnNetworkDevice(RadioKind deviceKind)
    {
        var radioRequest = await Radio.RequestAccessAsync();
        if (radioRequest != RadioAccessStatus.Allowed)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var results = await Radio.GetRadiosAsync();
        var networkDevice = results.FirstOrDefault(radio => radio.Kind == deviceKind);
        if (networkDevice == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        RadioAccessStatus resultsOn;
        if (networkDevice.State != RadioState.On)
        {
            resultsOn = await networkDevice.SetStateAsync(RadioState.On);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

And I call it like this

```
await SwitchOnNetworkDevice(RadioKind.WiFi);
```

I have a problem, though. Before this code worked fine, but now I get this problem (symbols not loaded for Windows.Devices.Radios.dll) after retrieving a list of radios:

[image]

It is just visible through debugger, when code is executed, nothing crashes, just networkDevice is always null and nothing gets switched on. How can I fix this?

Comment: Show the actual error rmessage, not the message generated by VS debugger. The message you reffered to just tells that VS debugger can not load debug information (debug symbols) for some system DLLs. But that is not related to the real error that appeared during your code execution.

Comment: You probably can't fix that unless someone gives you a Windows.Devices.Radios.*pdb* file

Comment: @MikePetrichenko there is no error when code is executed, just networkDevice variable is always null. And the reason is what you see in the debugger

Comment: @ThomasWeller but this exact code worked before (I must have changes something with project configuration or something like that recently and it stopped working). Now I cannot figure out why, since there were a lot of changes in repository
And also, Windows.Devices.Radios is a standard dll from microsoft, as I understand, why pdb file is not present and where can I get it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dxtecharts/debugging-with-symbols

Comment: @MikePetrichenko sorry, my fault, that is not the reason, but I just can't debug anything the way it is now

Comment: Disable native code debug in your project configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was somehow related to the fact that we switched project to 32 bit. When I changed it back to x64, problem went away for some reason, so we left it as x64 only